# How to disable Alt Gr key permanently in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab, ctrl-alt-delete

How to permanently disable the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key and make it a normal <kbd>Alt</kbd> key ?

Comment: Altering the keyboard layout is the best way. This can be done natively in Windows 10 Settings and doesn't require a registry hack though. Just set the keyboard layout to EN - United States. You will lose other keys your keyboard may have that are not part of the standard 101 keyset, such as ß and € keys, but they usually require the AltGr anyway. If you  have a fairly standard keyboard, this should not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Overflow post
[How to globally map AltGr key to Alt key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key)
has several solutions.

Save this as `AltGR_to_LeftAlt.reg` file and run it (after doing backup in regedit
of the key):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Or you could use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with this script:

```
LControl & *RAlt::Send {LAlt Down}
LControl & *RAlt Up::Send {LAlt Up}
```

More information is available in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this anywhere in my AutoHotKey script fixed my personal issue with AltGr:

```
RAlt::Alt
```

If you're interested what the issue was:
Using an international keyboard layout instead of English, I could no longer navigate backwards/forwards in my web browser using the rightalt+leftarrow/rightarrow shortcuts.